# Updating excel data with Userform to different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, userform, worksheet

I have created a userform that is used to enter new data into a worksheet. The form is loaded through a FormControlButton on the top of the worksheet. However I would like to place the FormControlButton on a different Worksheet and complete the userform from that worksheet. When I enter data into the userform from a different worksheet (say worksheet11 when the data set is in worksheet12) the userform does not enter the new data.

This is the code for the input button on the Userform:

```
Dim currentrow As Long

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim lastrow
Dim myfname As String
lastrow = Sheet11.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
myfname = Me.Reg8.Value
For currentrow = 2 To lastrow

If Cells(currentrow, 1).Text = myfname Then
 Cells(currentrow, 68).Value = Me.Reg10.Value
 Cells(currentrow, 69).Value = Me.Reg11.Value
 Cells(currentrow, 10).Value = Me.Reg5.Value
 Cells(currentrow, 9).Value = Me.Reg6.Value
 Cells(currentrow, 70).Value = Me.Reg7.Value
End If
Next

If MsgBox("Information has" & vbNewLine & "been updated") = vbOK Then
    Unload Me
    Sheet1.Select
End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to enter data into Sheet11 from Sheet1. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code. Given that button would be allocated on a sheet which you want to update, you can create a variable WS and assign it to current active sheet (Set ws = ActiveSheet). Please let me know is this solves your problem.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim lastrow
Dim myfname As String
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastrow = ws.Range("A1" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
myfname = Me.Reg8.Value
For currentrow = 2 To lastrow

If ws.Cells(currentrow, 1).Text = myfname Then
      ws.Cells(currentrow, 68).Value = Me.Reg10.Value
      ws.Cells(currentrow, 69).Value = Me.Reg11.Value
      ws.Cells(currentrow, 10).Value = Me.Reg5.Value
      ws.Cells(currentrow, 9).Value = Me.Reg6.Value
      ws.Cells(currentrow, 70).Value = Me.Reg7.Value
End If
Next

If MsgBox("Information has" & vbNewLine & "been updated") = vbOK Then
      Unload Me
      Sheet1.Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @A.Chelchko However I did change:                                                    
   Set ws = Sheet11
   lastrow = Sheet11.Range("A1" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row....in order to specify the Sheet.